# Django Rest Api - Justify Text

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a project that I must return. They asked me to build an API that justify a text to 80 char per line. Before that the user must authenticate through a unique token provided by the API by entering his email.

I'm still new to Django and API, and I have build the API that provides token to each user who register/login but I don't know how to take the token and the text of the user and return a json of the justified text.

Can any one help me? please!!!

Comment: I believe that should be make on the frontend side, you just return all text and then the frontend code handle the justify text to 80 chars.

Comment: @juliansalas I know but they're asking to do it with API

Comment: DRF has [TokenAuthentication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication), you can use that for authentication

Comment: Write a view that takes a input string using [Serializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/) and process it then return it as json as per the requirement using serializer also